# can I download Android to GSM kit?

Tags: gsm

I need to download Android to Gsm kit to transform and process some product like a smart bracelet by Bluetooth to read all measurement that or at least, temp, oxygen, heartbeat. can you please help me with that
Kind Regards

Comment: The AOSP contains information on building and flashing a device here: https://source.android.com/setup/build/building